# Почему сортировка массива срабатывает до его вызова?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка, замыкания

Имеется массив объектов, а также кастомная функция для фильтрации его элементов по ключу(параметру функции)

```
let users = [
    { name: "John", age: 20, surname: "Johnson" },
    { name: "Pete", age: 18, surname: "Peterson" },
    { name: "Ann", age: 19, surname: "Hathaway" }
];

// *1* console.log(users) выдает отсортированный массив

function byField (str){
    return function (a,b){
        return (a[str] > b[str]) ? 1 : -1 ;
    }
}

users.sort(byField("name"));
// *2* console.log(users) выдает отсортированный массив
```

Вопрос: почему первый лог выводит уже отсортированный массив до вызова метода?

Answer (score 3):

Потому что console.log в браузере «ленивый» и показывает состояние объектов в момент разворачивания, а не момент вывода.

Сделайте, например, `console.log(users.slice())` что бы вывести *копию* массива.

Comment: Осталось узнать что такое разворачивание))) А так мне кажется, что console.log асинхронна по природе, а массив передается по ссылке...

Comment: @Leonid момент когда тыкаешь мышкой в массив в логе что бы посмотреть что внутри

Comment: Вона чего... Это познавательно!

Comment: Действительно познавательно. @Alexey Ten , спасибо за ответ.